# Firebase Admin Nodejs cannot access a .json file in AWS Lambda layer

Tags: node.js, json, aws-lambda

I am trying to use FireStore-admin in NodeJS in AWS Lambda using layers. For this, I have zipped the node_modules and serviceAccount.json file in the following hierarchy and uploaded it to the layer:

nodejs->

- node_modules
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- serviceAccount.json (contains credentials to connect to FireStore collection)

The code is as follows:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

But I receive the following error when I run this lambda function:

```
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module './serviceAccount.json'
```

You can also find the image of the zip attached below:

[image: Hierarchy]

How do I access the json file and/or correct the hierarchy to get this working?

Comment: `serviceAccount.json` is in `.` relative to the layer file, but the layer could be extracted to a different path in the Lambda runtime. I have 0 knowledge on how JS `require` works, just throwing ideas around.

Maybe have a look at https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/master/sample-apps/blank-nodejs

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work so long as your file where this code lies is in the same directory as `serviceAccount.json`

```
import * as serviceAccount from './serviceAccount.json'
var admin = require('firebase-admin');    
    
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

Comment: I am not including the code with the zip file that I am uploading to the layer. The code is in the lambda code editor itself.